# form-row overlapping the other div flex on the navigation

Tags: html, css, flexbox

when i try to scroll the form the form-row content overlap on the navigation.
i am trying to make a form using bootstrap. but when i am adding a form-row or grid element for horizontal fields, the content or that form-row block overlap on my navigation panel on scrolling.
how can i make my form blocks below my navigation on scrolling.

```
body{
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu { 
    background-color: rgb(1, 9, 54);
    width:300px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#menu .logo{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: aliceblue;
    padding: 30px 0 0 30px;
    justify-content: flex-start;

}
#menu .logo img {
    width: 60px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#menu .items {
   margin-top: 40px;
}

#menu .items li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 15px 0;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

#menu .items li:hover{
    background: #254893;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#menu .items li:nth-child(1){
    border-left: 4px solid white;

}

#menu .items li i{ 
    color: blanchedalmond;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0 16px 0 25px;
}

#menu .items li:hover i,
#menu .items li:hover a {
    color : #f3f4f6;
}

#menu .items li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(134, 141, 151);
    font-weight: 300px;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

#interface {
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    margin-left: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

#interface .navigation {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
    position: fixed;
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
}

#interface .navigation .search {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 14px;
    border: 1px solid #d7dbe6;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#interface .navigation .search input {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 14px; 
}

#interface .navigation .search i {
    margin-right: 14px;
}
#interface .navigation .profile {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

#interface .navigation .profile i {
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 400;

}

#interface .navigation .profile img{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.i-name {
    color: #444a53;
    padding: 30px 30px 0 30px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 70px;
}

.values {
    padding: 30px 30px 0 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}

.values .val-box {
    background: #f3f4f6;
    width: 235px;
    padding: 16px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}

.values .val-box i {
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #254893;
    margin-right: 15px;

}

.values .val-box i:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: rgb(3, 114, 114);
}

.values .val-box i:nth-child(2) {
    background-color:rgb(80, 231, 181);
}

.values .val-box i:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: cadetblue;
}
.values .val-box h3 {
    font: 18px;
    font-weight: 600px;
}

.values .val-box span {
    font: 15px;
   color: #444a53;
}

#interface .fbuttons {
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

and here is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f8bc328439.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <section id="menu">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="profile-pic.png" alt="" class="">
            <h2>Farmer</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="items">
            <li><i class="fas fa-home"></i><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-user"></i><a href="farmer.html">Add/Modify Farmer</a></li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i><a href="store.html">Check Details</a></li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-tasks"></i><a href="details.html">Store</a></li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-infinity"></i><a href="buyback.html">Buyback</a></li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i><a href="home.html">Logout</a></li>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <section id="interface">
        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="n1">
                <div class="search">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="search">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="profile">
                <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
                <img src="profile-pic.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <h3 class="i-name">Add/modify farmer</h3>
        
        <div class="fbuttons">
        <a href="add-student.php"><button class="btn btn-danger">REGISTER A NEW FARMER</button></a>
        <a href="update-student.php"><button style="margin-left: 10px" class="btn btn-danger" >MODIFY FARMER DETAILS</button></a>
        </div>


<div class="container"style="margin: 10px 0 500px 10px;">
        <form>
  
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="">
    </div>
 
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="aadhar">Aadhar Number</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="mobileno">Mobile number</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" >
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="inputVillage">Village</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputVillage">
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="inputVillage">Taluka</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputVillage">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="inputDistrict">District</label>
      <select id="inputDistricts" class="form-control">
        <option selected>Choose...</option>
        <option></option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="inputPincode">Pincode</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputPincode">
    </div>
  </div>

   <h4> Farm Details </h4>

   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" >
   </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="inputVillage">Village</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputVillage">
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="inputVillage">Taluka</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputVillage">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="inputDistrict">District</label>
      <select id="inputDistricts" class="form-control">
        <option selected>Choose...</option>
        <option></option>
      </select>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="inputPincode">Pincode</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputPincode">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="inputPincode">Survey number</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputPincode">
    </div>
     
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="inputPincode">Area</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputPincode" placeholder="In acers">
    </div>
    
  </div>  


    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-check">
       <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
       <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
         Check me out
       </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
     
   </form>

  </div>
  
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're asking the "Sticky Header" question.

https://dev.to/akhilarjun/one-line-sticky-header-using-css-5gp3

It does mean restructuring your form a little bit. The nav section should probably go outside the "interface" section.

An alternate approach is the "holy grail" aproach.  Take what they have here: https://css-tricks.com/the-holy-grail-layout-with-css-grid/

and then just use the Aside, Nav, Article sections without the header and footer, and it's essentially what you're asking for.